# Merging jQuery plugins into one file

Tags: javascript, jquery

On my website, I am using several javascript files and these need to be loaded on each page. Some of them contain standard javascript functions and some contain jQuery plugins. I need to merge these into one file to reduce the amount of requests on the server. However when I put the scripts together into one file, I receive this error in my console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

I only receive this error with certain scripts, and it would seem as though they are conflicting with each other. Anybody have any ideas on how to avoid this conflict, apart from placing them in separate js files?

Thanks

EDIT: I'm including the scripts in the same order as they were originally called, so it cannot be anything to do with the ordering.

Comment: Usually there is a line number somewhere with the error message. If you could find that and post the lines around that number, it would probably help.

Comment: It's literally in the first line of a certain plugin called NProgress. This is the code causing the error - `(function (e) {`, and it's the same for the other plugins causing the error.

Comment: I think it's something to do with the leading `(`. Try re-writing it as `$(document).ready(function(e){`

Comment: @BeatAlex I found out the problem! I was compressing the files separately and putting them together. Turns out that the compressor took the last semi-colon off, so it crashed when I put them together!

Comment: Ah glad you sorted it!